# How would I print out this matrix?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have this code:

```
public static int[][] doubleMat(int[][] mat) 
{
    int row = mat.length;
    int col = mat[0].length;
    int[][] num = new int[row][col];

    for (int x = 0; x < row; x++) 
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < col; y++) 
        {
            num[x][y] = mat[x][y] * 2;
        }
    }
    return num;
```

And this in the runner file:

```
int[][] mat = {{45,101,87,12,41,0},{12,8,12,8,15,841},{-12,-1,-741,-1,0,74}};
System.out.println(Array2DHelper2.doubleMat(mat));
```

It keeps returning [[I@4617c264 instead of the 2D array. I'm pretty sure its something to do with toString but I'm not sure how to do it. I also have to print it as the whole array, not each individual spot printed out.

I've tried printing it using Arrays.toString(Array2DHelper2.doublemat(mat)), which I thought would work but it prints more of text similar to [[I@4617c264 (I forgot what they're called).

Comment: Well, what you see is the *Object*, not the *contents*. You already have a nested for-loop in your code, just go ahead and make it print out your matrix the way you like it formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Arrays.deepToString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) for printing multi-dimensional arrays:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
  public static int[][] doubleMat(int[][] mat) {
    int row = mat.length;
    int col = mat[0].length;
    int[][] num = new int[row][col];
    for (int x = 0; x < row; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < col; y++) {
        num[x][y] = mat[x][y] * 2;
      }
    }
    return num;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] mat = { { 45, 101, 87, 12, 41, 0 }, { 12, 8, 12, 8, 15, 841 }, { -12, -1, -741, -1, 0, 74 } };
    System.out.printf("Before doubleMat: %s%n", Arrays.deepToString(mat));
    System.out.printf("After doubleMat: %s%n", Arrays.deepToString(doubleMat(mat)));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Before doubleMat: [[45, 101, 87, 12, 41, 0], [12, 8, 12, 8, 15, 841], [-12, -1, -741, -1, 0, 74]]
After doubleMat: [[90, 202, 174, 24, 82, 0], [24, 16, 24, 16, 30, 1682], [-24, -2, -1482, -2, 0, 148]]
```